# How to make the color of ListPlot according to the order of PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

I make some fake data to illustrate my question:

This is the phone in Chinese:

```
phone = {"a", "ai", "an", "ang", "ao", "b", "c", "ch", "d", "e", "ei",
         "en", "eng", "er", "f", "g", "h", "i", "ia", "ian", "iang", "iao", 
         "ie", "ii", "iii", "in", "ing", "iong", "iou", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
         "n", "o", "ong", "ou", "p", "q", "r", "s", "sh", "sil", "sp", "t", 
         "u", "ua", "uai", "uan", "uang", "uei", "uen", "ueng", "uo", "v", 
         "van", "ve", "vn", "x", "z", "zh"}
```

Let every phone in phone list have a vector that is **similar phone has similar vector**

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[
              NormalDistribution[u, 0.3], {100, 2}], 
              {u, (ToCharacterCode[#][[1]] - 97) + 0.5*RandomReal[] & /@ phone}];

ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, phone, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]

(*ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, phone, LegendMarkerSize -> 15], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]*)
(*Nothing changed*)
```

You can find that there are many color are similar even it looks different.(marked in Box)

[image]

I want the color look like this that **similar phone has similar color**(marked in Box)

[image]

The color of `ListPlot` according to the `PlotLegends` maybe like this(the color is not beautiful~)

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
          Table[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", t/Length@phone], 
          Text[phone[[t]], {2 t, 1.5}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}], 
          Disk[{2 t, 0}, .9]}, {t, Length@phone}]}]
```

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: Are the blocks you marked the only similar phonemes in Mandarin?

Comment: @J.M. No,it's similar but not all.  I only want the color from `a` to `zh` has 
 changed  gradually

Comment: Then, you could just do something like `PointLegend[ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Subdivide[Length[phone] - 1], phone]`.

Comment: @J.M. But the color of `ListPlot` can't match the color in `PointLegend`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you are looking for one of the gradient color schemes? Since you are specifying the legend manually, you'll need to also specify the styles manually to enforce consistency between them.

```
$scheme = "Rainbow";

ListPlot[
 data
 , PlotLegends -> PointLegend[$scheme, phone, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]
 , PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[$scheme], Rescale @ Range[Length @ phone]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow   Exactly what I want !  That's beautiful  Thank you!